# Java: Enforce static method from super class (Mongo/Morphia context)

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, nosql

I'm designing the architecture for a ODM in Java.  I have a hierarchal structure with a top-level abstract `Document` class.  Implementations of DB objects will extend this class.

```
public abstract class Document {
    ObjectId id;
    String db;
    String collection;
}

public class Student extends Document {
    db = "School";
    collection = "Student";

    String name;
    int age;
    float gpa;
}
```

I want each class to be able to statically fetch results for its associated collection.  For example, I'd like to do something like `Students.get(Students.class, new ObjectId(12345))` which would return a `Student` from the database.  Note that I need to specify the class in the `get()` method, this is a restriction of the object mapper library I'm using (Morphia).

What would be the best way to enforce each class to have this `get()` method?  There are a couple constraints:

1. `get()` should be implemented as a static method
2. I'd like to avoid redundant code if possible and not have to specify the class for each implementation of `get()`.  For example if I have a `Student` and `Teacher` class, I want to avoid specifying `Students.class` and `Teacher.class` manually.  I'm not sure this is possible though, since `get()` is a static method.

I think this is a variation on the common *abstract static* Java problem, but I want to make sure I'm approaching it the right way first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your student class should look something like this:

```
@Entity(name="Student")
public class Student extends Document {
    protected String name;
    protected int age;
    protected float gpa;
    ...
}
```

Generic queries would something like this:

```
public <E extends BaseEntity> E get(Class<E> clazz, final ObjectId id) {
    return mongoDatastore.find(clazz).field("id").equal(id).get();
}
```

Why would you want to make this static? You'd hard-code dependencies and break polymorphism; making it impossible to use a mock implementation for tests (which doesn't need a real database).

Comment: I think the only reason I wanted it static is because it shouldn't be associated with any particular instance of the class.  Could you also explain what you mentioned about hard-coding dependencies and breaking polymorphism?  I'm having difficulty understanding this in my context. Thanks, really appreciate your input.

Comment: For a short answer take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17997568/573153
For a long, but really detailed answer see http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

Comment: And for a complete code example take a look at https://github.com/xeraa/morphia-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/net/xeraa/morphia_demo/persistence/MongodbGenericPersistence.java